# trying to get value in JSON string from amount

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a JSON string and I can't seem to extract the value from the amount attribute

```
var jsonString =[{"id":null,"recordtype":null,"columns":{"amount":1049.849}}]
```

I've tried accessing amount using:

```
jsonString[0].columns[0].amount
```

and also tried using:

```
jsonString.columns.amount
```

but all seem to generate an error.

Comment: That's not JSON, and it's not a string either.

Comment: columns is not an array. `jsonString[0].columns.amount`

Comment: Have you got the problem solved? If you have, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is

```
jsonString[0].columns.amount
```

Because the value under "columns" is immediately an object, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonString[0].columns.amount
```

is the way to go. Columns is not an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jsonString[0].columns.amount;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

You have an array, then just objects. So the answer is `jsonString[0].columns.amount`

It's useful to indent it, if in doubt:

```
[{
    "id": null,
    "recordtype": null,
    "columns": {
        "amount": 1049.849
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the JSON object like

```
var jsonString =[
{
  "id":null,
  "recordtype":null,
  columns:
  {
    "amount":1049.849
  }
}
]
```

Then you can access with jsonString[0]['columns']['amount'];

Here is the jfiddle link,
https://jsfiddle.net/hhLahiru/n0de3Lc8/

Answer (score 0):

i can do on console

var jsonString =[{"id":null,"recordtype":null,"columns":{"amount":1049.849}}];

jsonString[0]
Object {id: null, recordtype: null, columns: Object}

jsonString[0].columns
Object {amount: 1049.849}

jsonString[0].columns.amount
1049.849